# JGraphX Drop a Vertex in another Vertex

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx, jgraph

I try to create a GraphicEditor. I use a JTree and Drag & Drop to create Vertexes on a graphcomponent, but I don't know how to drop a created Vertex into another Vertex. 
How can I specify a Vertex as a Droptarget?

Thanks very much for you help!

Erik

Answer (score 0):

The `mxGraph` class has boolean method `isValidDropTarget(Object cell, Object[] cells)`. You can override this method and add a return condition such as

```
if (((mxCell)cell).isVertex())
{
    return true;
}
```

For this you would have to extend the `mxGraph` class and in your program use that instead of the default implementation, or you can modify the sources, depending on how you set JGraph to your application.

Additionally, the `Swimlane` style vertex should allow dropping on top of it by default.